# 18.04: Firefox Slowdown

Tags: firefox

My Firefox runs slow after a few hours (loading pages, video stream buffering, window movements, mouse commands etc). 3-4 tabs are generally open (I think its not much) in a single instance and a few extensions installed as well.

I think its one of them slowing down the browser. As soon as I run FF in a private window or run other browser, the PC's speed is back to normal.

Instead of trying out one by one sites and extensions, is there a way to know what actually is causing the problem? A log file for example. If yes, where to find it and how to interpret it? Thanks for the help.

Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (64-bit), 3.8 GiB, Firefox 75.0 (64-bit)